# tightness of measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to prove the following claim but I am struggling understanding the definition of tightness measure.

Let $\{S_n\}$ be a sequence finite subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ with cardinality $N_n$. Define
                    $\mu_n:=\frac{1}{N_n}\sum_{z\in S_n}\delta_z$

where $\delta_z$ is a Dirac measure at $z$.  Then the sequence of measures $\{\mu_n\}$ is tight.

The definition of tight measure  is  defined below :

A sequence of measures $\mu_n$ on a metric space $M$ is said to be $\textit{tight}$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a compact set $K_{\varepsilon}\subseteq M$ such that $\mu_n(M\backslash K_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Are you sure? Taking $S_{n} = \{(n,0)\}$, then $\mu_n = \delta_{(n,0)}$. Take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ let's say. Then no matter what compact set $K \subset \mathbb C$ you choose, then there exists $n_0$ such that $(n_0,0) \not \in K$. It is a contradiction, since $\mu_{n_0}(\mathbb C \setminus K) = 1 > \varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @DominikKutek The claim is under the assumption that $S_n$ is a finite  subset of $\mathbb{C}$. But it seems to me that the counter-example you gave me $S_n$ contains infnitely many points in there. Am I misunderstand something, please clarify?

Comment: You stated that $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of finite subsets of $\mathbb C$. And in my example, $S_n$ just contains only one point.